# VS Code not showing useful Python code snippets

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, code-snippets, python-language-server

Visual Studio Code is not showing Python code snippets anymore. I don't know if this is a bug from Python Language Server (which I have already tried Jedi, Microsoft and Pylance) or a VSCode problem.

It used to show useful code snippets for classes," if _*name*_ = '_*main*_' " and def statements also.

Unfortunately I don't have any pics of how it used to be, but now it doesn't show me these snippets anymore.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The snippets were removed in version 2021.1.0 (21 January 2021) of the Python extension, see their [changelog](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-python/blob/main/CHANGELOG.md).

You can get them back though by copying them from [here](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-python/blob/2020.12.424452561/snippets/python.json) and after that following these [instructions](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/userdefinedsnippets#_create-your-own-snippets).

Comment: Thank you, Guillermo. I was a bit lost without these snippets.

Comment: Good answer thanks. It's good to get the feature back but not sure why something this useful was removed in the first place.